# new PDO issue with var string defined

Tags: php, pdo

I have an issue when i call new PDO with a pre-defined variable..

I got this

```
define('SQL_BDD', 'ctms_demo');
```

in my config.php which is called in every .php pages so I can use it everywhere

when I call this

```
$hostname='localhost';
$dbname='ctms_demo'; 
$username='root';
$password='password';

$set = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

it works fine, but WHEN I change this line

```
$dbname=SQL_BDD;
```

It doesn't work anymore..

I looked for some topics talking about using double quote is ok.. so I really don't see where the problem is..

edit : I added this :

```
$dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s',$hostname,SQL_BDD);
print_r($dsn);
$set = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

and I got "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ctms_demo" , so the defined var is working.. I don't understand..

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'? Which error message/symptoms?

Comment: I don't have any error message and my page reload itself when its fine.. and it does..

Answer (score 0):

Constants aren't expanded inside of quotes, so break out of them:

```
$set = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=" . SQL_BDD, $username, $password);
```

The magic with variables inside of double quotes is the `$`.  How is the PHP parser supposed to know you mean constant `SQL_BDD` and not the text SQL_BDD? That would be a very expensive operation to check each word in a string and lookup it up in the defined constants table.

Comment: Thank you AbraCadaver I'm reading the url you just send

Comment: It doesn' work with constant so I tried this 

`
$dbname=SQL_BDD;
 
 $file = fopen('text.txt','w+');
 fwrite($file,$dbname);
 fclose($file);

 $dbname2 = $dbname;
 
 $file = fopen('text.txt','w+');
 fwrite($file,$dbname2);
 fclose($file);`

I have my 'ctms_demo' in my .txt file.. so why the new PDO doesn't understand that I want to put 'ctms_demo' in my $dbname var ?